# Does Mathematica implement the fast Fourier transform?

Tags: fourier-analysis

Is there a fast Fourier transform in *Mathematica*? Although looking in the help I could not find one.

I am looking to implement the equivalent of [`fft` in MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fft.html).

Comment: There is definitely something different going on with Fourier[] than the fft function in Matlab. If you take the fft(eye(n)) in Matlab you get the FourierMatrix of n. In Mathematica you do not. FourierMatrix[n] does exist, but the method of obtaining it via Fourier[IdentityMatrix[n]] does not work in Mathematica, so the fft and Fourier functions are different somehow.

Comment: I have put some notes on how Mathematica implements a Fourier transform [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85167/12558).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`Fourier[list]` computes the discrete Fourier transform of `list`.  I assume it uses the FFT when it can.

Comment: Note that the normalization used by *Mathematica* is quite different from conventional (e.g. physics, signal processing) normalizations. Check the definition you are using, and set the option `FourierParameters` accordingly.

Comment: Is there a way to strip it out ? In Matalab syntax I need to do the following :                                                        function fs = MyFFT(fx)

y = fftshift(fx);
tmp = fft(y)/sqrt(length(fx));
fs = fftshift(tmp);

Comment: `fftshift[vec_?VectorQ] := RotateRight[vec, Quotient[Length[vec], 2]]`

Comment: For reference: MATLAB's `fft(stuff)` is equivalent to *Mathematica*'s `Fourier[stuff, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]`. To do `fft(y)/sqrt(length(y))`, one doesn't need to do an explicit division, as the adjustment of `FourierParameters` is all that's needed: `Fourier[y, FourierParameters -> {0, -1}]`.

Comment: @J.M. Thank You very much for the explanation, well it is actually the answer to my question...

Comment: @J.M. - Where is the explanation for `FourierParameters`? Mathematica only says `is an option to Fourier and related functions that specifies the conventions to use in computing Fourier transforms.` which says little about how to get a correct RMS normalization (which is what I want).

Comment: @A.Vieira, under the fifth and sixth bullets of "Details and Options" for [`Fourier[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fourier.html) and  fourth and fifth bullets of "Details and Options" for [`FourierTransform[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FourierTransform.html), are explanations on how the `FourierParameters` option affects them. There should be similar notations in the other Fourier-related functions of *Mathematica* that take the `FourierParameters` setting.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks. That does it. I was checking the [FourierParameters](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FourierParameters.html) page which wasn't much help.

Answer (score 16):

[`Fourier`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Fourier.html) uses [FFT](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html#15565) when possible