# DFT: why are frequencies mirrored around the frequency axis?

Tags: fourier-analysis

I want to apply *Mathematica*'s DFT procedure, `Fourier[]`, to a Gaussian. Why a Gaussian? Because I know the analytical result.

So I define

```
a = 0.5;
h[t_] := Exp[-(t^2/a^2)];
```

The analytic `FourierTransform` of `h` using `FourierParameters -> {0, -2 Pi}` is:

```
HAnalytic[v] := Sqrt[Pi]*a*Exp[-a^2*Pi^2*v^2];
```

Then I create time values:

```
dt = 1/100;
tList = Table[t, {t, 0, 20000 dt, dt}];
```

and I create sample data:

```
inputData = h[tList]
```

I then create the frequency values:

```
dv = 1/((Length[tList] - 1)*dt);
vList = dv*Table[i, {i, 0, Length[tList] - 1}];
```

and carry out the DFT calculation:

```
HDFT = Re[Fourier[inputData]];
```

Now I plot it:

```
Show[
 Plot[HAnalytic[v], {v, 0, 1000*dv}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1.5}, {-1, 1}},
   PlotStyle -> Green],
 ListPlot[{Thread[{vList, HDFT}][[1 ;; 500]]}]
 ]
```

[image]

So far no problem. Only the scaling is different.

**BUT NOW MY QUESTION!**

Why do I get

[image]

i.e. the Fourier-transformed values are mirrored around the frequency axis, when using

```
tListSym = Table[t, {t, -10000 dt, 10000 dt, dt}]
```

I mean `h[tListSym]` gives really kind of the whole function to the DFT, as `h` is symmetric around $t = 0$, whereas `h[tList]` reproduces only the right hand side of h.

If I look at the values of `HDFT`, I can see that the values are alternatively positive / negative.

Can someone explain to me what is going on?

Comment: Does this help ? http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/431/what-is-the-physical-significance-of-negative-frequencies

Comment: Not really... as I am not wondering about negative frequenies. I am wondering why the amplitude of the frequencies is alternating for `t =ListSym = Table[t, {t, -10000 dt, 10000 dt, dt}]`.

Comment: @Hugh has recently written up an excellent [primer on DFT in *Mathematica*](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85167/27951). Maybe something in there might be of help to you. In particular, I think you might want to plot the `Abs[]` of your DFT values, rather than the `Re[]`.

Comment: Does not matter, as the fouriertransform of a real even function is a real even function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is that Fourier does not know your time values and does not see an even function. Thus if we generate your new input data and plot we get

```
inputData2 = h[tListSym];
ListLinePlot[inputData2, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The problem is thus how to tell Fourier that the first half of your input is for negative x values. We could change the phase of the values created by Fourier or we can put your input into the usual Fourier form of positive values then negative values - a shifted version. Thus

```
nn = Length[tListSym]
inputData3 = 
Join[inputData2[[(nn - 1)/2 + 1 ;; -1]], 
     inputData2[[1 ;; (nn - 1)/2]]];
ListLinePlot[inputData3, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Thus we are starting with the positive values and then putting the negative values after. Now when we do the Fourier transform we get what you want.

```
HDFT2 = Fourier[inputData2];
HDFT3 = Fourier[inputData3];
```

Here I have not taken the real parts as you did. We can compare the two versions

```
ListPlot[{Re[HDFT2][[1 ;; 500]], Re[HDFT3][[1 ;; 500]]}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ListPlot[{Im[HDFT2][[1 ;; 500]], Im[HDFT3][[1 ;; 500]]}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The imaginary part of the shifted version is zero because we have constructed an even function.
We now get what you want.

```
Show[
Plot[HAnalytic[v], {v, 0, 1000*dv}, 
     PlotRange -> {{0, 1.5}, {-1, 1}}, PlotStyle -> Green],
ListPlot[{Thread[{vList, Re[HDFT2]}][[1 ;; 500]]}, PlotStyle -> Blue],
ListPlot[{Thread[{vList, HDFT3}][[1 ;; 500]]}, PlotStyle -> Brown]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

On a secondary point I think you are off by one point in defining your frequency values. The increment should be 1/(Length[] dt).

I suppose a deeper question is why does Fourier do positive values then negative values? There is an assumption of a periodic function so it does not matter. However, it is often a nuisance as you have found.

With regard to getting the scaling correct you need to work out your version of Parseval's Theorem using FourierParameters.

Comment: I was hoping you might be induced to weigh in on this one :-) Let me also add a link to [a post in the DSP stackexchange site](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/2583) dealing explicitly with the math behind the even/odd function problem, just for reference. (+1)

Comment: @Hugh Thanks you :) "I suppose a deeper question is why does Fourier do positive values then negative values?" Yes ... But I think no I understand it. You have to think about it like this: It is a N periodic function, hence 0 = N, AND the first value given to the DFT defines 0. This is the same as sying the function lives on a ring. Therefore for getting a even function we have fist hand it the positive and then the negative values. I will make a small drawing: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1ecQW5sX1LJLWhfUUt6ckktY1U/edit

Comment: @newandlost Unfortunately I can't download or see your video -I will try when I get to another computer. However, I think I can see what is happening and I agree with your comment. There is also as solution that would involve adjusting the phase of the Fourier transform after the calculation i.e. making a transformation in time. Thus by writing   Exp[- I 2 Pi f (t-t0)] in the Fourier integral choosing a t0 and then taking this phase outside the integral it would be possible to correct the spectrum. Glad I could help.