# Perform a Fourier Transform on a wavelength scan

Tags: fourier-analysis

I have a plot of the power transmitted through a device as a function of wavelength, from 1500 to 1600nm. There is some Fabry-Perot noise, plus I suspect some other regularities. I would like to perform a Fourier analysis of the data, with the final goal of getting a frequency or, better, the cavity length at the origin of any periodicity.

I tried with `Fourier`, but I would like to correct for the fact that my scan doesn't start from 0, and I couldn't find anywhere the answer to that question. Moreover, I know that the Fourier transform will live in k-space, but I am having some problems in moving to a frequency space.
Can anybody give me some hints?

Comment: Can you post the data you are working with ?

Comment: I put together some information on Fourier [here] (http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/85139/what-do-the-x-and-y-axis-stand-for-in-the-fourier-transformation-in-wolfram-math/85167#85167) this may help. In particular Fourier does not require the x values of your data only the y values.