# Fourier Transform accelerogram seismic

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing

I have a seismic accelerogram. I tried to apply the Fourier Transform to interpolate function, but dosn't work.
So, i applied the `Fourier[signal,FourierParameters->{-1,-1}]`, when i Plot (ListLinePlot)

```
Abs[Fourier[signal,FourierParameters->{-1,-1}]]
```

Signal:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/tkag1h1tkbb34p8/elcentro.dat?dl=0

I obtained a Incorrect graphics (no sense ).

[image: Signal]

[image: Fourier Transform Obtainded By Fourier[]]

Can I solve It?

thanks in advance

Comment: I haven't looked at your data, but I think it must be 2d, that is, a list of lists.

Comment: Have you got time mixed in with the data? The input to Fourier should be a list of the data without the time coordinate.

Comment: @hugh so I must pass to "Fourier[]" only time coloumn? If yes, how plot The diagram frequency/Abs[FT]? Thx

Comment: @mikado I must verify but i think it is a list with two coloumn (time and acc). I import it by signal=Import["elcentro.dat"] and Then plot it by " ListLinePlot[signal]. Thx

Comment: Just use the ordinates. I put some information on using Fourier [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85167/12558).

Comment: @Hugh thanks ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like already pointed out in the comments: only use the ordinate values.

```
fData=Abs[Fourier[data[[All,2]],FourierParameters->{-1,-1}]]^2;
fData=fData[[1;;Floor[Length[fData]/2]]];
```

With a little bit more code, we can visualize it very well:

```
SR=(Length[data]/data[[All,1]][[-1]]);
Frequencies=(Range[1,Length[fData]]-1)*SR/Length[data];
ListLinePlot[Transpose[{Frequencies,fData}],PlotRange->All,Frame->True,FrameLabel->{Style["Frequency",16],Style["Powerspectrum",16]},ImageSize->1200,AspectRatio->1/8]
```

> [image: The Powerspectrum]

Comment: Julien Kluge, thx for your solution ;)