# Frequencies for Fourier coefficients

Tags: fourier-analysis, homework

I have been given the task of calculating the frequencies to which the fourier coefficients correspond.

So my input is a discrete signal `[1,4,0,1]`, which gives me `[3, 0.5+1.5i, -2, 0.5-1.5i]`.

What is an intuitive way to calculate the frequencies from this result (Or can I see them already based on the coefficients)?

Comment: You'll need to know the sampling rate $sr$ (in samples/sec). The first frequency is always DC (0-frequency). Then the frequency of the $n$th bin is sr/n (in Hz).

Comment: Have a look [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85167/12558) to see basic information on the use of Fourier.

Comment: Ah ok, so i could assume I measured my samples at 0s, 0.25s, 0.5s, 0.75s and 1s.  This would mean that my sampling rate is equal to 4 / 0.25 ? Which gives me 16. Then Frequence 0 would be 0 , frequence 1 would be 16? frequence 2 would be 8 and frequence 3 would 16 / 3 ?

Comment: @bills How are you counting? Mathematica usually starts at 1 so the frequencies are (n-1)sr/N. Where n goes from 1 to N. Also, the second half of the spectrum is the negative frequencies. So in the 4 term example we only have the DC value and one frequency, followed by the mid frequency term and the conjugate of the first frequency.

Comment: Not quite... that's a sr of 4 samples per second. But then you have posiive and negative frequencies -- really, read Hugh's answer and you will see the general case.

Comment: @greedsin Can we have some more information? Does the interval repeat so that it is {1,4,0,1,4,0,1,4,0...}. Usually for `Fourier` one has many more samples. What exactly are you after?

Comment: It was for a homework, I was just provided a discrete signal with n=4 like in the question. And  an sampling step of (1/30)s.