# Finding frequency from Fourier transform

Tags: plotting, fourier-analysis

I tried to find frequency using Fourier Transform, but notice that my code have some mistakes which I can't find.
So, my code is below:

```
T0 = 0.0;
T1 = 5.0;
gf = 1.0;

ja = Table[Cos[2 Pi*gf*t], {t, T0, T1, 1/10}];
ja1 = Fourier[ja];
ja2 = Chop[ja1];
ja3 = Take[Abs[ja2], ((Length[ja2] - 1)/2) + 1];

ListPlot[ja3, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {Style["Frequency (a.u.)", 
FontSize -> 16], Style["Amplitude (a.u.)", FontSize -> 16]},
PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, Mesh -> All]
```

And result is:
[image]
After I find frequency which is 1 Hz.

```
MaxAmp = Position[ja3, Max[ja3]][[1, 1]]
```

> 6

```
Freq = (MaxAmp - 1)/(T1 - T0)
```

> 1.

Than, I want to change frequency gf from 1 to 6 and I get next result:
[image]

When I tried to find frequency, I got 4 Hz which isn't correct.
I noticed that on the range between 1 and 5 it's work good, but if set larger value it's not correct. I also noticed that if you change the step from 1/10 to 1/20, then the result will be correct. But changing the frequency gf is constantly required to select this step, which is not convenient. How can I do it automatically, to prevent incorrect result.

Comment: You might be interested in `PeakDetect`.

Comment: This is a classical signal processing problem. (though I have not found a simple and concise answer on "signal processing StackExchange")

Comment: I have put information concerning the frequency axis and other basic aspects of Fourier [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85167/12558). This may help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you observe is perfectly normal. It is the consequence of the famous [Nyquist sampling theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem).

In your case, it is particularly clear that the problem is not due to the Fourier transform. Compare:

- `ja` at $6 \text{ Hz}$ `gf = 6.0; ja6 = Table[Cos[2 Pi*gf*t], {t, T0, T1, 1/10}]`
- `ja` at $4 \text{ Hz}$ `gf = 4.0; ja4 = Table[Cos[2 Pi*gf*t], {t, T0, T1, 1/10}]`

They are exactly the same:

```
   Max[Abs[ja6 - ja4]]
```

> 3.030908857*10^-14

(It's a very special case of aliasing due to not respecting the theorem)