# How to fit one function into the form of another?

Tags: fitting, fourier-analysis

I have a slightly complicated periodic function of one variable `t`, say `g[t]`.

I want to do a least squares fit of that function into the form `A*Cos[Ω*t]+B*Cos[2Ω*t]`, and figure out the values of parameters `A` and `B`.

Is there a way to do this in *Mathematica*? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want numerical values for A and B or symbolic values? Numerical is very straightforward. Symbolic may end up with very large expressions. It would be nice if we had some code from you so that we could play with it.

Comment: Numerical values will do! Thanks.

Comment: [This post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85167/12558) shows how to use `Fourier` to calculate a spectrum of values for A and B.  Do you really just want the first and second harmonic? Roman's answer below will work fine for calculating individual values. An example from you would clarify what you want. If you can, please edit your post and add an example.

Comment: Thank you! I think I Roman's answer suffices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are regular orthogonal-function integrals: assuming that the period of your function `g[t]` is `T=2π/Ω`, you can compute

```
A = Ω/π*NIntegrate[g[t]*Cos[Ω*t], {t, 0, 2π/Ω}]
B = Ω/π*NIntegrate[g[t]*Cos[2Ω*t], {t, 0, 2π/Ω}]
```

If your function `g[t]` is simple enough, you can even replace the numerical integrals by analytic ones (`NIntegrate` becomes `Integrate`).

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer! I will try this later, but just to clarify, will NIntegrate work to approximate any function? g(t) is very ugly and Integrate itself cannot solve it.

Comment: As long as the numerical integrals converge, you're safe and get an optimal fit in the least-squares sense. If `NIntegrate` struggles too much, it will throw messages, and in that case you can come back here to ask another question about "How do I make this numerical integral converge?" and using options/tricks/methods.

Comment: @Houndbobsaw I would recommend the method option `Method -> "Trapezoidal"` for `NIntegrate` in this case, unless `g[t]` has singularities. The smoother `g[t]` is, the faster the convergence, in general. The main issues of numerical integration -- speed of evaluation of the integrand, singularities, oscillatory behavior -- are quite distinct from the issues in symbolic integration.  (Hugh's `Fourier` method will also approximate `A` and `B`.)