# Identifying the three frequencies using fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, frequency

The following simple function has clearly three frequency components:

```
 fun[x_] = Cos[ x] + Cos[2 x] + Cos[3 x];
data = Table[fun[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi], 0.1}];
ListPlot[data, ImageSize -> 200]
```

How can one show these frequencies using the Fourier transform? I tried the following

```
ListLinePlot[Abs[Fourier[data]], PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 200]
```

But it doesn't  seem to lead to the proper answer.

Edit: I would expect the Fourier plot to show three peaks corresponding to three frequencies in the ratio 1:2:3.

Comment: Try `ListPlot` instead of `ListLinePlot` and you'll see the both frequencies!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, thanks. With two frequencies, it was looking suspicious to me. Now with three frequencies, it is still showing two peaks with ListPlot.

Comment: I have put some basic information on `Fourier` [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85167/12558) which may help. Your three frequencies are a perfect match to your time interval and are multiples of the fundamental frequency so you get the first three points in the spectrum.

Answer (score 1):

`ListPlot`shows the frequencies:

```
fun[x_] = Cos[ x] + Cos[2 x] + Cos[3 x];
data = Table[fun[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi], 0.1}];
ListPlot[Abs[Fourier[data]], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Shouldn't there be three peaks?

Comment: Yes, every point stands for a peak of the special frequency.

Comment: Then there are six frequencies depicted in this plot?

Comment: @Patrick No there are only three frequencies for your signal. More details you might find in `Nyquist–Shannon sampling theorem`