# Discrete fourier transform and convolution -- scaling factor?

Tags: fourier-analysis, convolution

I am trying to convolve a square wave (a diffraction grating `phgrating` with slits size `\[CapitalLambda]`) with a point spread function (`PSF`) to account for the finite size of the pixels.

I should get a "smoother" square wave -- indeed, this is what I get. But it always ends up being rescaled depending on the paramters of `phgrating` and `PSF` in ways I do not understand.

Definitions of `PSF` and `phgrating`:

```
PSF[rx_, x_, \[Gamma]_] := Exp[-(x^2/(2 rx^2))^\[Gamma]]

phgrating[x_, \[CapitalLambda]_, \[Phi]_] := \[Phi]/2 + 
  Sum[(\[Phi])*2/\[Pi] 1/(2 n - 1)*
    Sin[(\[Pi] (2 n - 1) x)/\[CapitalLambda]], {n, 1, 500}]
```

Function that generates discrete sets from `PSF` and `phgrating` for faster computation (`psf` and `gr` respectively):

```
PSFdiff[\[CapitalLambda]_, \[Phi]_, Nslits_, rx_, \[Gamma]_] := 
 Module[{x},
  gr = Table[{x, 
     phgrating[
      x, \[CapitalLambda], \[Phi]]}, {x, -Nslits \[CapitalLambda], 
     Nslits \[CapitalLambda], \[CapitalLambda]/100}];
  psf = Table[{x, PSF[rx, x, \[Gamma]]}, {x, -Nslits \[CapitalLambda],
       Nslits \[CapitalLambda], \[CapitalLambda]/100}] // Quiet;
  {gr, psf}
  ]
```

## Example 1:

```
{gr, psf} = PSFdiff[1, \[Pi], 3, 0.1, 1];
```

The grating, as expected, goes from `0` to `\[Pi]` with each "slit" size `1`:

```
ListLinePlot[gr]
```

[image]

The point spread function also makes sense:

```
ListLinePlot[psf, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

Now I try to compute the convolution via the convolution theorem, and I get this:

```
ll = InverseFourier[
    Fourier[Transpose[psf][[2]]]*Fourier[Transpose[gr][[2]]]] // Chop;
ListLinePlot[ll]
```

[image]

Apart from the fact that it is **shifted** with respect to the original phase grating, the scaling is fine.

## Example 2:

Same parameters as before, just chaning `\[CapitalLambda]` from `3` to `5`:

```
{gr, psf} = PSFdiff[1, \[Pi], 5, 0.1, 1];
```

and this is the result:

[image]

**shifted** again but now also **scaled**!

I tried to play around with `FourierParameters` but did not manage to make sense of all the outcomes.

Comment: When you convolve in the frequency domain should you also conjugate one of the two Fourier transforms you are multiplying? Does that make a difference?

Comment: Maybe that explains the apparent shifting of the square wave. But not the scaling factor?

Comment: In [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85167/12558) I use `FourierParameters ->{-1,-1}`. This means that the total square in the frequency domain equals the mean square in the time domain. Do you need to get the area under the PSF equal to one?

Comment: Hi, I use your `FourierParameters` convention, I normalised the kernel, and I multiply the InverseFourierTransform by the step-size between points... and now it works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing two scaling factors: (I) Factor in convolution theorem; (II) Factor in Kernel.

### Factor (I)

To compute the factor in a linear transform (Fourier, convolution, etc.), it is helpful to first try the delta function. In the discrete case here, it is [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta#Digital_signal_processing).

The default Fourier transform (FT) in Mathematica has a $1/\sqrt{n}$ factor beside the summation. After product of two FT and an inverse FT, we left factor of $1/\sqrt{n}$.

```
n = 10;
kd = Table[Boole[i==1],{i,n}];
fkd = InverseFourier[Fourier[kd]*Fourier[kd]];
fkd[[1]] - 1/Sqrt[n]  (* = 0 *)
```

Conceptually it is (FT and invFT are non-scaled Fourier transform)

$$
    \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \textrm{invFT}\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \textrm{FT}[a] \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\textrm{FT}[b] \right] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \left( \frac{1}{n} \textrm{invFT}\left[ \textrm{FT}[a] \cdot \textrm{FT}[b] \right] \right).
$$

The RHS shows the factor $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ and the usual convolution theorem.

### Factor (II)

Usually, one would wish the PSF do not change the signal amplitude, particularly the DC signal. So simply normalize the kernel to summation one would do it.

### Result

Put these two factors together we have the correctly scaled convolution theorem:

```
ll = Sqrt[Length[gr]]/
    Total[Transpose[psf][[2]]] InverseFourier[
     Fourier[Transpose[psf][[2]]]*Fourier[Transpose[gr][[2]]]] // Chop;
ListLinePlot[ll]
```

[image: Corrected example 2]

This correspond to your example 2.