# Taking Fourier transform with WolframAlpha gives unexpected result

Tags: fourier-analysis

I have noticed that WolframAlpha's definition of the Fourier Transform is different than the one in my book of formulas. In my book the Fourier transform of $f(t)$ is defined as:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t)e^{- i \omega t}dt$$
The inverse transform is defined as:
$$\frac{1}{2 \pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F(\omega)e^{i \omega t}d\omega$$
Using WolframAlpha with a simple case is shown [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=FourierTransform%5Bt%5E2%2C+t%2C+w%5D). This looks more like the inverse Fourier transform, except we divide by $\sqrt{2 \pi}$ instead of $2 \pi$.

Trying this simple case I could get the same answer as in my table of fourier transforms by multiplying WolframAlpha's answer with $\sqrt{2 \pi}$.

Will I generally get the right result by taking WolframAlphas answer and multiplying by $\sqrt{2 \pi}$? (Since WolframAlpha also integrates in the other direction). Is there a way to get the right (according to definiton above) answer right away using WolframAlpha?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange. There are many definitions of how you scale Fourier transforms. Look up `FourierParameters` to see options for scaling. I have put some notes on numerical Fourier transforms [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85167/12558) that might help.

Comment: Particularly, this one: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/118092/1871

Comment: The part I'm still wondering about: Does the direction of the integral never matter?

Comment: What do you mean by direction? Please expand.