# Fast method for numerical integral (Fouriertransform?)

Tags: numerical-integration, performance-tuning, fourier-analysis

I want to numerically compute following integral (as fast as possible):

\begin{equation}
f(x) = \left| \int e^{ \mathrm{i} p x / 2} f(p) \ \mathrm{d}p\right|^2 ,
\end{equation}

where $f(p)$ is given as a table on a discrete grid in p.

Example function:

```
f[p_] := Exp[-p^2] Exp[I p] Cos[p]^2 p^2
```

Generate the table on a discrete grid in p:

```
fp = Transpose[{Range[-5, 5, 0.01], 
   f[p] /. p -> Range[-5, 5, 0.01]}]
```

How I do it:

```
fx[fp_] := 
  ParallelTable[{x, ((fp[[All, 1]][[-1]] - fp[[All, 1]][[1]])/
        Length[fp[[All, 1]]])^2 Abs[
       Sum[fp[[All, 2]][[n]] Exp[I fp[[All, 1]][[n]] x/2], {n, 1, 
         Length[fp[[All, 1]]]}]]^2}, {x, -20, 20, 0.1}];


fx[fp] works fine, but takes 16 seconds on my machine.
```

Is there a way to do this much faster?

Edit: I have an answer code to my own question. I think it might be helpful for others.

Comment: `Fourier` performs a fast Fourier transform, perhaps that's what you are looking for.

Comment: I can give Fourier only a list of values and it doesn't know about the grid, or am I missing something?

Comment: It is good so that it does not know about the grid. That is why it is so fast.

Comment: As long as the grid is uniform and the wave length is a multiple of the interval's length, `Fourier` should work. Of course, you have to adjust some constants.

Comment: Could someone please write down an example code how I can map the result from 'Fourier' back to a proper grid? The results I get with 'Fourier' do not make much sense for me. I get large values at the boundaries and extremely small values in between.

Comment: This has already been asked many times here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/85139/what-do-the-x-and-y-axis-stand-for-in-the-fourier-transform-domain/85167#85167

Comment: Thank you for the link. I tried this approach but it seems to me that for Fourier there is a fundamental trade off between Range of my grid and the resolution I can get in Fourierspace. .

Comment: Thank you for the link. I tried this approach but it seems to me that for Fourier there is a fundamental trade off between the range of my p-space grid (max-value - min-value) and the resolution I can get in x-space. This is not the case for the code I gave above. Am I correct? Unfortunately, I know my numerical $f(p)$ only for a quite narrow grid and it has quite narrow features, so my grid spacing in p-space is quite small. The resolution in x-space is therefore really bad. Is there a way around that?

Comment: You cannot get more information than it is already contained in FFT.

Comment: Then I guess it comes down to carefully choosing the discretization range, right? I have no experience with FFT, sorry :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We want to reproduce the result of following code with a FFT

```
Abs[FourierTransform[f[p], p, x, FourierParameters -> {a, b}]]^2
```

This code does it correctly for all positive values of the x-space:

```
 Clear[fft2]
fft2[fp_(*f(p) in Matrix form*), dp_(*grid resolution*), a_, b_] := 
 Module[{pgrid, samples, n, factor, transform, xgrid},
  pgrid = Range[fp[[All, 1]][[1]], fp[[All, 1]][[-1]], dp];
  samples = Interpolation[fp][p] /. p -> pgrid;
  n = Length[pgrid];
  factor = 
   Sqrt[Abs[b] n/(2 Pi)^(1 - a)] Exp[
     2 Pi I pgrid[[1]]/(n*dp) Range[0, n - 1]]*dp;
  transform = 
   Chop[Fourier[samples, FourierParameters -> {0, b}]*factor];
  xgrid = 
   RotateRight[Range[-Ceiling[n/2] + 1, Floor[n/2]]/(n*dp), 
     Floor[n/2] + 1]*2*Pi;
  Interpolation[Transpose[{xgrid, Abs[transform]^2}]]
  ]
```

It takes as argument $f(p)$ stored in the following form $fp=\{\{p_1,fp_1\},\{p_2,fp_2\}...\}$ and a proper grid spacing $dp$ depending on what resolution of the FFT you require, $a$ and $b$ as the Fourier Parameters and returns an interpolation function.

Not sure how I can make this work for negative x-values as well but for me they are not necessary.

Comment: Negative `x` values should give the same result as their positive counterparts, since the integrands (summands, using `Fourier`) are complex conjugates of one another and an absolute value is taken at the end.