# How can I make an FFT in Mathematica using data from a file?

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, data, fourier-analysis

I need to calculate the seismic moment of an earthquake data, but I don't know how the FFT is applied in some data, my data is a plain text that I must import it to Mathematica

```
data={-0.009142829110620023,-0.007237242507199119,-0.005856729791687345,-0.0016757444456758895, 0.004101942711928292, 0.005277199807646435,-0.0012104291223735055,-0.0068205115634768975,-0.002808109650848882, 0.0040857888113286535,-0.0012738713758881984,-0.018890708886353625,-0.031091881280288357,-0.02698622184395104,-0.011821764971736771, 0.006529962757055874, 0.024002302834804243, 0.033469218305463774, 0.028144857229519135, 0.008940462135516544,-0.01816283650535824,-0.04352074489975321,-0.05709770048044003,-0.05489633148359469,-0.03833782092192627,-0.00845350192267141, 0.0298483267259239, 0.061455825449889874, 0.072268048614125, 0.05738160601557756, 0.02231607364790296,-0.01586381283070766,-0.041664472605338225,-0.048822603239018846,-0.03747423856755443,-0.014750787555201275, 0.0069345264383843495, 0.01808332570824239, 0.01904777652291207, 0.009880892145985403,-0.011157209173877584,-0.03230967155813778,-0.03596380350816044,-0.01937315633517632, 0.00728709535709263, 0.03525832276262811, 0.05606242152672219, 0.05840645454389285, 0.04156807365180021, 0.018380856021558735,-0.002305355563315299,-0.018954007639006433,-0.026156227342111465,-0.018470244011170315,-0.0027245597522543253, 0.006457560184263524, 0.0020006428688122482,-0.012749219546641205,-0.03145186607703128,-0.04735072562552381,-0.04723315059528739,-0.022067979280536883, 0.014085326264247864, 0.03723790931333207, 0.035828121139498, 0.016571853409565008,-0.0067240226524118716,-0.02604352874670279,-0.03579336850077075,-0.02974880522535298,-0.00829113579732785, 0.01792161725638784, 0.035793486414550775, 0.04187419062196674, 0.04468628009036788, 0.04662815510553379, 0.03960645825622895, 0.026686956746007857, 0.024381126775322542, 0.04020915782409727, 0.06015207140865371, 0.06359596673022301, 0.04291323805481557, 0.007502528852522933,-0.028975649880973946,-0.055674770146941534,-0.05619900043625424,-0.026097361427974263, 0.01048475843001462, 0.027302786827213814, 0.024285876207532548, 0.01841649179573205, 0.01788664798079997, 0.019212977384237342, 0.019220243745944474, 0.02179998683193043, 0.03044272988228456, 0.03440590493060758, 0.022072108012586814, 0.001746540077376478,-0.010607865375382492,-0.01036596611498064,-0.00033481958474115424, 0.01740298423434944, 0.037654101847632605, 0.048974525441205626, 0.04138319368700481, 0.01541978841411778,-0.017751778172700867,-0.04491054179073279,-0.05683353329937288,-0.04671917196852715,-0.0176246595494267, 0.013939825908926352, 0.03499281949538097, 0.044079393676789716, 0.04442399992276593, 0.038426734865811996, 0.02989051457086152, 0.023270462889036267, 0.019523140310609158, 0.016657054429383127, 0.00923896969597028,-0.0032859331444297615,-0.011428137494623531,-0.006120717018768457, 0.0095397869057069, 0.02823144047645781, 0.048624310593245235, 0.059928523196290176, 0.04580640607232442, 0.012697177688504927,-0.015331484100913714,-0.02923483603758195,-0.034713517891858434,-0.029116085873108738,-0.008291648590693888, 0.018608398277614326, 0.036881176640940795, 0.043923630425973796, 0.04459413401182003, 0.03542894418299688, 0.01671300498500952, 0.004235143541346084, 0.012404611355848166, 0.032234154126411924, 0.044353243833101075, 0.047155845374009644, 0.04445650473195265, 0.032582909674489166, 0.011256910802414786,-0.012963965083235596,-0.029208572114164187,-0.031131386833909116,-0.023670794796344864,-0.018037831554538076,-0.014157445723302227, 0.0003009756997305986, 0.024046370591387686, 0.03967489174879327, 0.038601382549648754, 0.02843468512834806, 0.014878568653338378,-0.0022957544002923627,-0.019795433596707837,-0.031040740090802578,-0.03328677628797319,-0.030327810756260978,-0.023542322873420556,-0.010920479882278181, 0.006921711931432113, 0.021872647054741783, 0.02105642330774077, 0.00369080609900962,-0.015745386820509678,-0.024966810742611013,-0.023824972335606858,-0.01276146861546147, 0.009926871899174433, 0.034640642048515316, 0.04452395983945579, 0.033794595910341056, 0.012953173652292004,-0.006486342465638399,-0.020198603958907057,-0.028234506145594074,-0.034869175031498466,-0.04024671486162456,-0.036703329786664164,-0.021097911165574156, 0.00012917180634882102, 0.020493569063214718, 0.03431771425528989, 0.031106377926795267, 0.007638714615137091,-0.021452326077192035,-0.03921559172408905,-0.04110083986879091,-0.03403702961078375,-0.0262934279799707,-0.014673147502764943, 0.005769022788880024, 0.024997312471079978, 0.031022546159888257, 0.024904829651907948, 0.010915914965568934,-0.009781806163809784,-0.03172025741842082,-0.04711353812389592,-0.05431999748878651,-0.05496663138828756,-0.049235341281529954,-0.03703753074345294,-0.018874286713461773, 0.0028484071521379557, 0.0215031405316256, 0.03036628314596997, 0.025477611564815105, 0.005740196728335251,-0.018503792533340477,-0.030168131612448256,-0.02068172879959028, 0.004644652223316913, 0.030404939228883054, 0.041650681444176954, 0.030262922378021962, 0.0004838314508431755,-0.03277356027145695,-0.054566912854108876,-0.05596417411318176,-0.0409929636749862,-0.021832075363375187,-0.004730161980626762, 0.008965886616805415, 0.018330989562758814, 0.022313495317435567, 0.019796947844171228, 0.01144761035688104,-0.0008447176844043589,-0.01207267315305758,-0.014237860690483587,-0.004295195119663549, 0.010739930700837605, 0.023470762409450348, 0.034117041375061136, 0.0399512219552347, 0.03566656437531732, 0.02594546649539159, 0.020894845636880297, 0.024250322477601748, 0.03328198007760867, 0.04381714598593863, 0.052576225677435966, 0.055405833814992506, 0.04544965015050128, 0.021420433097037686,-0.007606596911424041,-0.028686832490302825,-0.031631466206466806,-0.01609465813496181, 0.0067772122663621506, 0.02523176895753041, 0.034317858244206564, 0.03167389897317895, 0.01621337098034973,-0.00816563926623941,-0.030486578839591497,-0.03797541754590567,-0.025292346042720272, 0.0015698750671040026, 0.030882641726433815, 0.05463419889484129, 0.06564734740133837, 0.05610854304106464, 0.029401199734364825, 0.000439451847171369,-0.017415512986451432,-0.019405753055482217,-0.009921494726306573, 0.0038297108600171886, 0.013878851162514633, 0.011314111364503627,-0.003140805975998747,-0.01959217304771261,-0.02990693759091537,-0.030470572445818227,-0.01919508271785665, 0.00122432870997349, 0.01895945111563394, 0.01968496173092765, 0.0025300580608940445,-0.019378707790353677,-0.036704789593793107,-0.04266127146829648,-0.029133596158543638, 0.0012792440490472059, 0.030324267702447723, 0.041711973138961925, 0.03687363948489132, 0.02322634446452318, 0.004529128499998925,-0.014520829213799373,-0.02377518355690184,-0.017413529156353722,-0.0048229756969021325, 0.0010563530581663306,-0.0019362340766871902,-0.007523874456416318,-0.010030816011515875,-0.00711600795129029,-0.0013001638449975901, 0.001981147087559995, 0.003434495003219299, 0.007337044744611396, 0.009336579648684744, 0.002039316496669455,-0.008523347425870709,-0.008200084465339638, 0.0035647776246123825, 0.01760319128509538, 0.0323574815818214, 0.043848439948094606, 0.04244578845881937, 0.03000655560356476, 0.014310319094837235,-0.005883103398415883,-0.030433343230616666,-0.0473998795434279,-0.04719627318761418,-0.032771465652112086,-0.010377179371000555, 0.015131596887279492, 0.03279581873722413, 0.028415738189050244, 0.002079221903957508,-0.027089313118542294,-0.04104575800669451,-0.04090868454937531,-0.03800204477320098,-0.03396897541246585,-0.02478271678249418,-0.014716453831325452,-0.009854960208852993,-0.006078719414729748, 0.0036078828595754544, 0.013571167362029322, 0.014921884515801091, 0.008958365473030855,-0.00026374304085340734,-0.01115426345599331,-0.019848309270294757,-0.018310958978115147,-0.00702079835566933, 0.002157253551825451, 0.004387466250901059, 0.00345764156432604, 0.0012155586197797241,-0.0025789446853233915,-0.008975760422315763,-0.0183621239884553,-0.027271208613353498,-0.0321243235444114,-0.03348611649246101,-0.032415164652775295,-0.027216743077090787,-0.015913078015479566,-0.0010379058884615055, 0.015035645571911734, 0.03383573650810484, 0.051055047262415824, 0.058403301894026115, 0.054254867756160945, 0.041036939712053265, 0.019541775382402562,-0.008460588134283013,-0.03553505872408238,-0.0530890682645106,-0.056754541608253356,-0.04502509430709582,-0.021044508609765353, 0.00638652918057574, 0.026470079638644572, 0.03109626192490931, 0.01957840234601489, 0.0011171749070561531,-0.011474276868220874,-0.01412944390724262,-0.0099930651059605,-0.0003330659031559334, 0.013342170169123563, 0.0222388530379038, 0.016687878044365213,-0.00019431327439785721,-0.01843857573396907,-0.03331518545212789,-0.042456059936267186,-0.041177886465105694,-0.029793374661441406,-0.017537483695024884,-0.012389152521749007,-0.014301429009888256,-0.018679729293335504,-0.021174682534403112,-0.01670019039386918,-0.0033062818828315144, 0.012731078151608198, 0.023752871157934008, 0.02460884044644331, 0.012562284825902815,-0.008343362452451944,-0.02806014064421279,-0.038632715955183056,-0.03636034322443972,-0.02045532300922555, 0.003995157424989846, 0.028305697793709637, 0.045534366344356716, 0.051515245733052675, 0.04378981894889757, 0.025766378903509676, 0.008225749032746399,-0.0008257115966920249,-0.0026339459602775345,-0.004592892319386646,-0.008632122927701946,-0.01043257700901529,-0.011808479526379234,-0.014237374421208504,-0.01260180083040139,-0.0062810135994626004,-0.00019884743271227274, 0.0052531619398587335, 0.012116940650515712, 0.015566714094592256, 0.008932431180494728,-0.008644621445908968,-0.03277632864374049,-0.055617825337206064,-0.06628400928391566,-0.05475374345615798,-0.025985122710290406, 0.0028265585329304214, 0.02229240224534639, 0.030959028030478414, 0.02908245672864646, 0.020366681994541745, 0.01044355882470538, 0.00649153953788502, 0.015918234137164027, 0.036663592393861084, 0.054554667097975414, 0.057775487345137704, 0.04508325799615634, 0.020212001376821675,-0.010274592030938121,-0.038301419465356326,-0.053725236402298475,-0.045983396854560016,-0.01738496467435709, 0.016179607395133685, 0.039879214996315436, 0.04974305865242233, 0.04825945987110883, 0.03795944034109229, 0.026132818430956568, 0.01990307715043231, 0.017131290766998597, 0.0112386612455095,-0.001333138431253974,-0.019206994552261148,-0.037638153397797296,-0.050041468641755314,-0.04796030849984975,-0.024516603710681678, 0.015127862016098604, 0.05113418881558221, 0.06547023095185636, 0.0561706517018798, 0.03141505062450095, 0.002087181072853672,-0.019478004616341388,-0.0266714867854708,-0.022826963174360084,-0.015256253192679614,-0.008143537349252501,-0.003963734428499232,-0.007058691691100614,-0.0141243578307525,-0.013269851799606734,-0.0031330321754305737, 0.004078619840097407, 0.0035951223946683836, 0.006145892316301499, 0.01751094610064079, 0.028551287192672012, 0.031826241250553194, 0.02553250884714563, 0.005780135852066173,-0.025407007928988687,-0.05308271378618689,-0.06031626839896045,-0.04408273036570837,-0.01806521104146367, 0.00281418752702487, 0.018046183055406152, 0.0339111353574389, 0.04624282264387929, 0.04607476454432159, 0.039720743804352754, 0.03807978303925365, 0.034420012595534205, 0.021659396200705804, 0.005629307426069344,-0.01182860528487748,-0.0349572837500625,-0.057612798534499625,-0.06459027174723855,-0.04935325070096857,-0.017802189866243646, 0.017195074922724627, 0.037632447052658925, 0.031257320761935284, 0.006726739313658577,-0.01763531980122694,-0.03426832090399479,-0.038992877842244165,-0.025519010627830067, 0.0003280276833739431, 0.025283867859984467, 0.04213939018991994, 0.04452218874022967, 0.030614096528968435, 0.011828701986114477,-0.001502910478148746,-0.010794985506204755,-0.016889110640977444,-0.01436550546125294,-0.0020940155178921557, 0.01443810616308169, 0.031191897206336555, 0.0453079180438889, 0.049559010421004863, 0.03888909859865069, 0.01683679559524601,-0.008914370486548308,-0.030168550075738317,-0.04078381542810385,-0.03662611664671178,-0.016399349048951257, 0.013375466626355872, 0.03959524793514147, 0.05274742421160421, 0.054033143681891604, 0.05035561974648229, 0.046747199542552575, 0.04178178719341281, 0.03101264161888126, 0.015760771372002418, 0.004182911671769268, 0.003003314096162656, 0.010015788750896568, 0.020353188925709392, 0.03168961947240342, 0.039977750885200065, 0.04118428475166537, 0.03853371840584093, 0.039558200265977665, 0.040701834317610305, 0.029244361935642137, 0.005111790323514745,-0.017207954366679507,-0.028999668180713818,-0.03317313527826677,-0.030858367583444117,-0.01929043202172967,-0.001866932011652294, 0.014230448045711374, 0.026368092559039324, 0.03412160555953811, 0.03382864503402694, 0.021254725331403095,-0.00043391727152551537,-0.017814573896284415,-0.016840656730164934, 0.001280284236397676, 0.02112606201315798, 0.03347576126006399, 0.03996186376661965, 0.037601691269569255, 0.018960733416384462,-0.010959446939516362,-0.033544395656848094,-0.03443739943359535,-0.016001581892049515, 0.006184164256291382, 0.020990064825611346, 0.02774664724511823, 0.022691635012069826, 0.00041892183415163193,-0.03209910594506914,-0.053327394379843074,-0.048496218425023364,-0.02756589812491844,-0.006975956779618944, 0.00920048925699928, 0.022319704985226632, 0.03004107594097761, 0.03066457808694729, 0.025183924007697953, 0.011503076748876922,-0.011235997257948604,-0.034390721356895956,-0.04693561418608561,-0.0481256355873314,-0.04569176527629535,-0.04180249555960329,-0.02896398101447927,-0.007770420084259599, 0.006483472840483671, 0.004148939849473189,-0.006402482866597673,-0.013452960423572032,-0.01698768661746052,-0.019547324605811562,-0.016452266135910002,-0.005286921880224435, 0.006680896807438652, 0.013690016512259609, 0.016081413500653927, 0.012963759310801171, 0.00437437083873802,-0.006568300981553232,-0.015305790279363542,-0.017744252558910305,-0.012970554023484562,-0.004203670606357016, 0.0016216157127756856,-0.0012314101423416238,-0.012588564648032539,-0.02491221046293412,-0.028355939675318277,-0.02055405958365326,-0.0046893866356874534, 0.016284827170993617, 0.03572984347866848, 0.0426827800645716, 0.031224811809537005, 0.008394792767382527,-0.011842131600062191,-0.02159783386626071,-0.023195714837241137,-0.02118709394934409,-0.013367079519531103, 0.0005852364185090203, 0.010493998448766835, 0.011252431822935696, 0.010875638265167279, 0.01255595311279935, 0.007868972556941653,-0.004225672112951724,-0.01478076121111614,-0.023437863245718504,-0.03583870857071467,-0.04657763046142827,-0.041913573512117726,-0.02040085927313686, 0.004914223307475643, 0.021947453343383865, 0.027287132451798396, 0.025692313909166965, 0.020277333803711967, 0.00965803026544662,-0.0038285570842187403,-0.012827293519688705,-0.012548987843869916,-0.00579290342358114, 0.0021715032008259947, 0.007444658182675437, 0.009535276801773655, 0.009674846281808123, 0.004683826048231455,-0.008224481001802238,-0.024017710225372545,-0.0328264193279751,-0.026638917150996002,-0.0049195811046038405, 0.023089087189077186, 0.04599724888239172, 0.057725416934341904, 0.056767584976948574, 0.043332681420801426, 0.018885626614716083,-0.009796944312115528,-0.031827306338480764,-0.039552933155151036,-0.03334759561361974,-0.01930186735903299,-0.002246296163495718, 0.014155801989434277, 0.02415727468763754, 0.025928482124533348, 0.0248465763690794, 0.02674173530686094, 0.03151072233380933, 0.033255848179328834, 0.02922917727180521, 0.022979051232506625, 0.017271840341579178, 0.009649285839460684,-0.003386163284976655,-0.017574690465056164,-0.023160143377627854,-0.014673821231829812, 0.002849625195981574, 0.017018364246181996, 0.019944157849557685, 0.015788734840218307, 0.013157873617485008, 0.011618038920034357, 0.008262033823319428, 0.0061252205240089185, 0.00528099268033878, 0.001970645328291242,-0.0030081226511652496,-0.0032647874402679748, 0.003980920552176569, 0.01290811496238232, 0.016939224775330792, 0.013575618571142329, 0.006680825414968836, 0.004700850767131867, 0.009015928655777102, 0.012971562338945192, 0.01089430678272963, 0.00314438200763676,-0.004682468560829058,-0.006528472213750126, 0.0003596529414493195, 0.010892160458103513, 0.015769544566549176, 0.012970548067547666, 0.006988171543801353, 0.001969394639558558, 0.0002456874158240903, 0.0033457085697536993, 0.012055911105697523, 0.021342462868873917, 0.02233579527480574, 0.011813068173069737,-0.005230588522059721,-0.020216591241119592,-0.029392577272895074,-0.034510567075786064,-0.03478734879321251,-0.026770007773159445,-0.011971509481927906, 0.0021949843340560923, 0.011621988354640638, 0.018625306727901143, 0.02216490440108129, 0.017221018292032788, 0.004098971611626543,-0.012445098835411943,-0.027439390739200164,-0.03480795809216829,-0.032129737182945164,-0.024794044761442577,-0.015310885663620774,-0.00016762900647673682, 0.016553064258492605, 0.022823782941769188, 0.016242313521405847, 0.0066343800551662375,-0.0003698302702233785,-0.005609619548998825,-0.009061093614756956,-0.010323962645713789,-0.008977124222570325,-0.001575861329309267, 0.013483649399630423, 0.02563194252768286, 0.02222391392947329, 0.006156853711624707,-0.00837962178204328,-0.013203055494947878,-0.01169881029507661,-0.00805525060120969,-0.0033859169413355266, 0.0004816166491334424, 0.0014886158149487005,-0.0007560863152842748,-0.0023923215365283085, 0.0007844337649983681, 0.002733657043489288,-0.007877293341425487,-0.029974789236155864,-0.05009752020505943,-0.058341582157797355,-0.05445547134285162,-0.04096439815769841,-0.02160297832097823,-0.002761669030048402, 0.009025919641819686, 0.008253259876864403,-0.004622143069512241,-0.02242664105710672,-0.038994693101859546,-0.04947797305098631,-0.04669874124314346,-0.025244339481872435, 0.009456503648690008, 0.040301272920490815, 0.05435328866216632, 0.05043796163744935, 0.03168756689658196, 0.003326334598350012,-0.02601015007050187,-0.04476497679444235,-0.046282437161827936,-0.03426593861602244,-0.015370349166072357, 0.006709682971027982, 0.02719118767069274, 0.0363436657663336, 0.028794706606021115, 0.01451384143662452, 0.0091510541151672, 0.013183100455232442, 0.014666952296513875, 0.012465901888753655, 0.014139088948302478, 0.016325509855400468, 0.011489930915461268, 0.0064241961126874445, 0.01320747313783678, 0.0278045036018961, 0.036160671058359926, 0.03302910947199434, 0.023386312955554836, 0.013219906675944592, 0.0043668645535539135,-0.001146865441995366, 0.005744802376286409, 0.029991898281580893, 0.05772522665947346, 0.06954085958222628, 0.06201915353644517, 0.0472806119610132, 0.029908712456999983, 0.003030366440793463,-0.027199480927937367,-0.04004365416673291,-0.025607312301957154, 0.001622515066478664, 0.02358497784781315, 0.0375395457552348, 0.045662843914132424, 0.04545143020802712, 0.03156742218532819, 0.005752905299390556,-0.019678091340800705,-0.03425615014620892,-0.03794857480209061,-0.035097285359328496,-0.02460586108750046,-0.005437480197237159, 0.01287097657033814, 0.017896168275752324, 0.011090042208578224, 0.002497637927271437,-0.007476967626205905,-0.022583320547894456,-0.03873910614020149,-0.04950757539971537,-0.051117976196969075,-0.03940400905785791,-0.014750635356218102, 0.013406696482221989, 0.03179880221578628, 0.03079528029639436, 0.014632293312817223,-0.002901176359192854,-0.012930582790095643,-0.012825553581697393,-0.004601821929205788, 0.004821928112455033, 0.008046706239403054, 0.0038714611228237114,-0.0034673427095195156,-0.011408802037825447,-0.017733866174392085,-0.01849753375741172,-0.012928922148530383,-0.0032649997955817443, 0.007825098695952994, 0.016150016199009586, 0.01920808101361334, 0.018497615291436294, 0.013307055345376009, 0.0013791133627125383,-0.010320306599229943,-0.011672388590664735,-0.004322781120544804, 0.004796389484462898, 0.01253468221686455, 0.014905162143763407, 0.00679567247471084,-0.0105290046918736,-0.029099331842419304,-0.03897204192994242,-0.034168756331410005,-0.019575917020913068,-0.005702119160801004, 0.003638300026746611, 0.01028596047629065, 0.012599852638888246, 0.008854759283309371, 0.00337786622846174, 0.0010639267152736554, 0.0020735726785952274, 0.0021941049725381517,-0.0007533089288846721,-0.0024403500355634116, 0.0022609602892975193, 0.011533588871047384, 0.01767689420806268, 0.01732907676365043, 0.011145245262929943,-0.001139483479657318,-0.013626745137419027,-0.014474431633738436,-0.0022099970767594395, 0.012429508819366577, 0.024720552696085064, 0.03477961347681717, 0.035474541799051795, 0.021629137864313162, 0.0016669562146166613,-0.012913912508597239,-0.020092955181985603,-0.021850450317742864,-0.018608520303889257,-0.011699479092206859,-0.0028704750858620964, 0.00721811221298097, 0.014845959127259502, 0.01671098468422986, 0.01694567422632643, 0.018325398609438107, 0.017480081630880575, 0.014073967298460641, 0.012476422806053905, 0.01480167223040414, 0.01801875404578781, 0.015909561020216244, 0.0030588947178051976,-0.01701856206845786,-0.032321399385104754,-0.036494782998208554,-0.032979880536489516,-0.024712549327004167,-0.010421994248010227, 0.0075337657030291666, 0.02002288096776444, 0.020995430081462402, 0.01563182656017813, 0.010790045237695419, 0.004182764472402604,-0.007276253429622082,-0.016876006508647085,-0.01484528821211702,-0.0019441506433474137, 0.01447506931510983, 0.03173019488849111, 0.04685858899365925, 0.05329029394288309, 0.047680574179987376, 0.033018284488861925, 0.015645323651665557,-0.00034821161600376727,-0.01375569720135152,-0.02011746425541031,-0.013636611903709548, 0.0006099834979819717, 0.009028184421464901, 0.006883942456058287,-0.0010398821842289312,-0.013924382498483765,-0.031579614375129884,-0.045056527695628665,-0.044273418657351994,-0.029718532381255373,-0.009201202117356767, 0.011977484757263332, 0.030935373638906593, 0.04430147536082108, 0.04746337436840904, 0.03774254551917811, 0.020733600563723642, 0.00627511487404056, 0.0003238001961499119, 0.002108546987408171, 0.005467890949229216, 0.005810613512999542, 0.004649700795896582, 0.004467717638880299, 0.003307386417967533, 0.0032992232360301065, 0.012677598307244681, 0.02987997316930877, 0.04463611444757838, 0.05232697818235025, 0.05098539786995436, 0.035893429201346354, 0.01003337060517019,-0.012537947423449011,-0.022089736258400716,-0.02110665619683194,-0.015056176483112886,-0.007375664347917773,-0.0014663533743771524, 0.0011261584482008704, 0.0026349730415893852, 0.006967907972978274, 0.014081296424314264, 0.017476341994637882, 0.010189836579638489,-0.0059140269730636975,-0.020603473188992086,-0.02482371242628626,-0.016985816867592977,-0.00023871206470876737, 0.022975791434991094, 0.04339281487681685, 0.044976679280449475, 0.024393982217130218,-0.004573500084019791,-0.027098503651912652,-0.038790037198172506,-0.038983469736263744,-0.02556060618860403,-0.002033561607505872, 0.02200421460473598, 0.03668284265330919, 0.03713727838243076, 0.024613917489119584, 0.003634814456755757,-0.0201196750568429,-0.0395077913136223,-0.04726492191445459,-0.041949244484279585,-0.026822150925947887,-0.00611875743270041, 0.014092691651155136, 0.028733304544567195, 0.0349388106230805, 0.03067751258318033, 0.01823077610281679, 0.0034964948825102044,-0.012082958627552655,-0.031225755158632466,-0.050449880624204434,-0.0598407351833959,-0.05414104137580634,-0.03694905592082247,-0.015361026057804985, 0.005645727090389231, 0.023548816108325207, 0.03468955348543154, 0.03379763172343071, 0.020888301497174716, 0.0025417744963753207,-0.013663506397032944,-0.024356388463933582,-0.03289593555749574,-0.040403627303251075,-0.04191157786503661,-0.034322240644053134,-0.020922274106496084,-0.00843770451889824,-0.0016497463400875555,-0.0005898178086582818,-3.0102660278826332e-05, 0.00358825248951446, 0.005189988273994871,-0.0034162568765836593,-0.019857412629759385,-0.030603089866036628,-0.027969619186949377,-0.018914543709969568,-0.014641100951674927,-0.01619281227619523,-0.01885830765487488,-0.022865078866089704,-0.028231199531122526,-0.02831736587092441,-0.01673526900975172, 0.0029396938294684485, 0.01815831086134388, 0.017180755267623377, 0.0013886089606487068,-0.017022064548237084,-0.029136956448333626,-0.03379589588250882,-0.03372291224786931,-0.030699995534058853,-0.025976993932660043,-0.022053905418882344,-0.022289204236572536,-0.027436857058474966,-0.03046951587976251,-0.02348621725497177,-0.009619810043067343, 0.0012578535313708219, 0.00682565629469776, 0.009714436591951245, 0.007046566560573678,-0.004279696739953049,-0.018842068931313384,-0.028430827399188865,-0.03213798280880552,-0.03217339325551024,-0.029445957856915488,-0.02437714353245596,-0.014516871935649007, 0.0003239835031350513, 0.012601221858953808, 0.01480509401889838, 0.010280177707600391, 0.006229921211675019, 0.0007519152190806965,-0.008108214960872884,-0.01559144901073382,-0.018097974985538747,-0.014276530218728344,-0.0054086912619272605, 0.0055906173507273785, 0.017103671297606482, 0.025295985743066646, 0.023097986899180075, 0.008157991954794925,-0.0114314497000307,-0.024888930622744387,-0.02612561581012639,-0.01447719324447927, 0.004327813494392369, 0.022179585374455725, 0.033274209366934815, 0.03425762720858981, 0.025743909299796704, 0.014226092898244662, 0.007066088320734209, 0.0033570740975639203,-0.0011457643512217432,-0.004549748638007829,-0.0050793809606867295,-0.004655418863455991,-0.004487638610647804,-0.005364454408103286,-0.008769159814305896,-0.01464043479110319,-0.019888611042415898,-0.022804478786574614,-0.02591052463960674,-0.028467719128144685,-0.022437520851607325,-0.006538340680409935, 0.006310921617263068, 0.005866909011251394,-0.00241059756680224,-0.010518786249623808,-0.021274887638991394,-0.03448112678670025,-0.04017049952772802,-0.03354542917535576,-0.020580953210268826,-0.010489538315142408,-0.008891765590177993,-0.016454796035161708,-0.02850874882977149,-0.0383795770828877,-0.04050136655983324,-0.031594713179578314,-0.013795720074848002, 0.008095632926205782, 0.030192347688473693, 0.04570920012114079, 0.04313892349857454, 0.02153759871268756,-0.0022058686932111713,-0.014607403207205355,-0.017457167403486556,-0.01573272125647492,-0.009807086787731685,-0.00224463488997526, 2.4094374535834447e-06,-0.006871310550068578,-0.020402194251239382,-0.03283442988469269,-0.03489687590070983,-0.02565229879975338,-0.014622932278192925,-0.00636480129869683, 0.004169387406377517, 0.015777687715496893, 0.019667774499708905, 0.014061609561122793, 0.005268187665358338,-0.0033516289091184872,-0.010150154393800747,-0.009643733399105379,-0.0011299134983496207, 0.0063049848377312485, 0.004998723406748508,-0.0020343271866082443,-0.00973894954463132,-0.017418921882873223,-0.023065233929978047,-0.02377171942955724,-0.017470465285063425,-0.00471253103637956, 0.008267145563113636, 0.013592943256149941, 0.00737910818370435,-0.007005266411152828,-0.02266780384803896,-0.0339035997354984,-0.03502302482579177,-0.023478365080353916,-0.002000424507364282, 0.022599506016807908, 0.040246082261617716, 0.045094373169398745, 0.03953804794473232, 0.027600230696414214, 0.010447481948285545,-0.010485470944317397,-0.028302527733833054,-0.03624409375978468,-0.03538648497153436,-0.02779543644879869,-0.012883480956064374, 0.007577837248673303, 0.027743583511482022, 0.039194953680437475};
```

I did this...

```
sis1 = Import["data.dat"];
data1 = Flatten[sis1];

ListLinePlot[data1, AxesLabel -> {Time, Amplitude}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

At this point I need to apply the fast Fourier transform to the data, to calculate the seismic moment, it should look like this.

[image]

can someone help me? thank you

Comment: See [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85167/12558) for details on `Fourier`.  Also, can you put your data in Mathematic form as a list. Further, unless you tell us the sample rate we can't work out a frequency axis.

Comment: What have you checked in the documentation? I ask because there is a fair amount of material on Fourier transforms.

Comment: Just use [`Periodogram`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Periodogram.html) or [`Spectrogram`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Spectrogram.html). It's a lot easier to use that interface than setting up the fourier transform yourself. Also you need to deal with `{-5 - 3.01027 e, -6 + 2.40944 e}` in your data first, as these aren't being interpreted as numbers properly.

Comment: It would be interesting to know what form of Fourier transform is normal for seismic work. In my area, structural dynamics, I do a lot with the real and imaginary parts (or modulus and phase). If relationships between two horizontal directions and the vertical direction are important then the full information in the spectrum is needed.

Comment: Thanks Hugh for you reply, I'll tried :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to sort your data. Here is the time history. The data is in c1.

```
ListLinePlot[c1]
```

[image: Time history]

Now we take the Fourier transform and plot

```
 n = Round[Length[c1]/2];
ft = Fourier[c1, FourierParameters -> {-1, -1}];
    ListLogLogPlot[Abs[ft[[1 ;; n]]]]
```

[image: Fourer transform]

Hope that helps.

***Edit***
A comment below suggests you want the power spectral density. You may want this but if you have a transient a simple Fourier transform is appropriate. There are issues with the best scaling. [Parsival's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem) is the usual guide for how to scale. You may have a standard for your discipline. Scaling is achieved by means of the `FourierParametes`. You need to read the documentation for details.

Comment: @xg3istx Note that what @Hugh is plotting is the square root of the power density, while the example that you wish to match appears to be the power density. Also, `n` in the above is something like `1+Floor[Length[ft]/2`.