# Why does the reported primary frequency with Mathematica's discrete Fourier transform scale with the length of the input signal?

Tags: fourier-analysis

I am testing Mathematica's DFT algorithm using one of the test cases provided in the documentation, of a noisy sine function with a frequency of 0.15 cycles per sample:

```
FourierTestData[n_] := Table[N[Sin[30 2 Pi x/200] + (RandomReal[] - 1/2)], {x, n}]
```

I find the estimated period according to the FFT:

```
Frequency[data_] := TakeLargest[Drop[Abs[Fourier[data, FourierParameters -> {-1, 1}]], -Round[Length[data]/2]] -> {"Index"}, 1];
```

I test this method across a range of numbers of points (without changing the period or any other parameters), like so:

```
Table[{i*200, First[First[Period[FourierTestData[i*200]]]]}, {i, 1, 200, 0.1}]
```

I find that the reported frequency is equal to the actual frequency times the number of points, i.e. the length of the test sequence. Why would this be the case?

Comment: For the discrete Fourier transform, the complex amplitude `a[[i]]` represents a frequency of `i-1` cycles per total length of the input sequence. This is implicit in the definition of the DFT, reflected in the detailed definition in the *Mathematica* documentation.

Comment: I have put some notes on how Mathematica implements `Fourier` [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85167/12558) . The notes explain how to generate a frequency axis.

Answer (score 1):

As per Hugh and John's comments, this is because in a discrete Fourier transform, the frequency represented by the n-th point (in cycles/sample) is equal to `(n-1)/N`, where `N` is the total number of points.