# fast fourier transformation question

Tags: fourier-analysis

I was testing fft on mathematica using simple functions and ran into problems.

I first tried a simple cos function with the following code:

```
f1[x_] := Cos[2 \[Pi]*x];
Sample = Table[f1[x], {x, 0, 2, 1/100}];
fft = Abs[Fourier[Sample]];
p1 = ListLinePlot[fft, PlotRange -> Full, DataRange -> {-1, 1}]
```

which does give me the graph of two delta functions. Here is my first question:
**Why do I have to manually adjust DataRange in order for the peak to be at the correct position namely -1 and 1?**[image]

I then tried the addition of two cos functions and this is where it started to give me problems

```
f2[x_] := Cos[2 \[Pi]*x] + Cos[\[Pi]*x];
Sample1 = Table[f2[x], {x, 0, 2, 1/100}];
fft1 = Abs[Fourier[Sample1]];
p2 = ListLinePlot[fft1, PlotRange -> Full]
```

Supposedly it should give me four peaks at -2,-1,1,2 but the graph is not showing so. **Where might it go wrong in this case? And what datarange shall i use?**
[image]

Comment: I have put some notes on `Fourier` [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85167/12558) in answer to another question. You may find them helpful. Let me know if you need more.

Comment: Hugh I have successfully applied your code to simple functions, however it fails for some more complex function, for example a single impulse. I did read through your points but am unsure if i understand them completely, could you have a look at this question pls?https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/263082/fft-of-a-signal-does-not-produce-satisfactory-result

Comment: Hugh pls ignore my above question, I just realised I made a stupid mistake. Thanks for your notes, tremendous help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see it better, you'd need to set the frequency scale yourself. This is how I would do it. Assume some sampling frequency

```
fs = 1000;  (*1000 hz. Assumed sampling frequency*)
sample = Table[Cos[2*Pi*100*t], {t, 0, 1 - 1/fs, 1/fs}];
fft = Fourier[sample];
fft = fft[[1 ;; Length[sample]/2 + 1]];
df = fs/Length[sample];
frequencyAxis = Range[0, fs/2, df];
data = Transpose[{frequencyAxis , Abs[fft]}];
ListLinePlot[data, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The above shows `f` at 100 HZ as expected because we used `Cos[2*Pi*100*t]` as the signal.  Now lets add another one at say `200` hz. Just change the line

```
sample = Table[Cos[2*Pi*100*t] + Cos[2*Pi*200*t], {t, 0, 1 - 1/fs, 1/fs}];
```

Now you'll get

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And so on. The units on the x-axis are in `Hz`. It goes up to half the sampling frequency (Due to Nyquist limit).