# An unknown defect with an approach in constructing scaled coordinates for obtaining and plotting Fourier series

Tags: plotting, fourier-analysis

I am having trouble scaling a set of coordinates and generating these coordinates into stepwise functions.

I start with the points from a plot:

```
points = {{395.4416644777464`, 
    207.63931734339303`}, {391.15890276860114`, 
    240.47382378017346`}, {382.59337935031067`, 
    219.06001523444706`}, {378.3106176411653`, 
    209.0669045797748`}, {369.74509422287485`, 
    177.65998537937617`}, {361.1795708045843`, 
    250.4669344348457`}, {355.46922185905726`, 
    204.78414287062958`}, {346.9036984407667`, 
    236.19106207102823`}, {341.19334949523966`, 
    184.79792156128497`}, {332.6278260769492`, 
    220.48760247082885`}, {326.9174771314222`, 
    214.77725352530183`}, {322.6347154222768`, 
    260.4600450895181`}, {316.9243664767498`, 
    219.06001523444706`}, {314.06919200398636`, 
    241.90141101655524`}, {304.076081349314`, 
    119.12890868772422`}, {295.5105579310235`, 
    327.5566451994606`}, {278.3795110944425`, 
    156.24617683364988`}, {269.8139876761519`, 
    251.8945216712275`}, {264.1036387306249`, 
    196.218619452339`}, {258.39328978509786`, 
    286.1566153443896`}, {249.8277663668073`, 
    233.33588759826466`}, {241.26224294851679`, 
    173.37722367023093`}, {231.26913229384448`, 
    184.79792156128497`}, {224.13119611193568`, 
    286.1566153443896`}, {215.56567269364515`, 
    160.52893854279512`}, {199.86221309344583`, 
    303.28766218097076`}, {184.1587534932465`, 
    72.01852988712619`}, {172.73805560219247`, 
    587.3775222209401`}, {162.74494494752017`, 
    83.43922777818022`}, {149.89665982008435`, 
    260.4600450895181`}, {145.61389811093912`, 
    254.74969614399106`}, {138.47596192903032`, 
    317.56353454478824`}, {131.33802574712158`, 
    183.37033432490318`}, {124.20008956521278`, 
    193.36344497957543`}, {119.91732785606749`, 
    160.52893854279512`}, {112.77939167415872`, 
    214.77725352530183`}, {108.49662996501345`, 
    199.07379392510256`}, {105.64145549224995`, 
    250.4669344348457`}, {101.35869378310466`, 
    324.70147072669704`}, {98.50351931034115`, 
    224.77036417997408`}, {91.36558312843238`, 
    220.48760247082885`}, {81.37247247376007`, 
    96.28751290561604`}, {75.66212352823305`, 
    200.50138116148423`}, {72.80694905546954`, 
    351.82562821795045`}, {54.24831498250671`, 
    154.8185895972681`}, {41.4000298550709`, 
    240.47382378017346`}, {35.68968090954388`, 
    236.19106207102823`}, {32.83450643678037`, 
    280.4462663988626`}, {12.848285127435787`, 
    131.97719381515992`}, {7.1379361819087705`, 227.62553865273765`}};
```

Then I generate a time-dependent stepwise function:

```
Clear[t];
f[t_] = Piecewise[
   Partition[Sort[points], 2, 
     1] /. {{a_?NumericQ, b_}, {c_, d_}} :> {b, a <= t < c}];
```

which I then shift to put the highest peak to the y-axis:

```
f1[t_] = f[(172.73805560219247` (t + Pi)/Pi)];
Plot[f1[t], {t, -Pi, Pi}]
```

This gives a nice plot:

[image]

which of the function I can transform to a Fourier series:

```
FD[t_] = FourierSeries[f1[t], t, 15]
```

and plot to a nice function:

```
Plot[{FD[t]}, {t, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

Once done this, which is all fine, I then go over to generating the same piecewise function as above, **but not time-dependent, but position dependent**. In order to do this, I simply scale the coordinates by the command:

```
pointsq = ScalingTransform[{15, 1}][points]
```

again, generate a piecewise function:

```
f[x_] = Piecewise[
   Partition[Sort[pointsq], 2, 
     1] /. {{a_?NumericQ, b_}, {c_, d_}} :> {b, a <= x < c}];
```

Shift the coordinates so the highest peak is at the origin:

```
f1[x_] = f[(2591.070834032887` (x + Pi)/Pi)];
Plot[f1[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}]
```

then I obtain a Fourier-series by:

```
ud[x_] = FourierSeries[f1[x], x, 15]
```

The interesting thing is that even these functions should be different, they look the same:

Here is the Fourier series of the time-independent (position dependent ) function:

[image]

and when I plot these two as $f(t)\cdot u(x)$ I get a symmetric plot, which means the are equal:

[image]

So the Fourier transform gives the same result, because the function is only scaled by a scalar. So if this is caused by the Fourier transform it self, or not, I don't know.

So, how can I "stretch" the x-axis on the given plot of the Fourier series by the scaled factor I used for the point-set (the factor is 2591.070834032887`)? The function to stretch is $ud(x)$

Thanks

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Which axis are you trying to scale? Also if you are doing numerical calculations why are you using `FourierSeries` rather than `Fourier`? There is also the option `FourierParameters`. Do [my notes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85167/12558) on `Fourier` help?

Comment: f1[t] and f1[x] are the same functions. They are defined over the same interval -Pi..Pi

Comment: @Daniel, that is because it is a Fourierseries , that needs to be defined over that interval. Or can I manage with 0 to pi?

Comment: @Hugh the axis to scale is the x axis. The Fourierseries gives the exact correct function, based on the data. What is the advantage of Fourier over FourierSeries? I gave your post a thumb up too. What I am doing is basically generate  an acceptable wavefunction that looks like the wave-reading on the dataset.  THe dataset is taken out of a graphics image of a wave-pattern. This is a time-dependent wave pattern. The FOurierSeries command gives a very nice copy of that wave-pattern on the graphics, and it gives also an analytic function.

Comment: That time-dependent wave pattern, I need to transform to a time-independent, and that is done by scaling the x-axis from time to position (using the velocity of the wavetrain multiplied to the x-entries of that point -set.