# InverseFourier, Time response from the pressure over frequency

Tags: inverse, fourier-analysis

the problem I'm trying to solve is much more involved, that is I'm trying to get the Time Response for an Impulse Input for a loudspeaker starting from the pressure it generates over the frequency:[image].
As you can see the Re part (Red) is symmetrical over the frequency, while the Im part (Blue) is anti-symmetrical, so, after the discretization and the InverseFourier, I would expect a Real result. None!
So I decided to make a simple example for your attention.

```
a = -(\[Pi]/2); b = \[Pi]/2; n = 9;
Rx = Range[a, b, (b - a)/(n - 1)];
T = Table[Cos[x] + I Sin[x], {x, Rx}];
G1 = ListPlot[Re[T], PlotRange -> {All, {-1.1, 1.1}}, PlotStyle -> Red];
G2 = ListPlot[Im[T], PlotRange -> {All, {-1.1, 1.1}}, PlotStyle -> Blue];
Show[{G1, G2}, GridLinesStyle -> Green]
```

[image]
Then I would expect that the

```
Z = InverseFourier[T, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]
```

would give me real numbers. I get however

```
{0.558593 + 0. I, 0.197397 - 0.0718465 I, 0.107042 - 0.0898191 I, 0.0575418 - 0.0996653 I, 0.018928 - 0.107346 I, -0.020304 - 0.11515 I, -0.072473 - 0.125527 I, -0.17356 - 0.145634 I, -0.673165 - 0.245012 I}
```

What is the correct way to proceed?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The convention in Fourier transforms is to put the negative part of the spectrum after the positive. As the function is periodic this is the same as your version. For some notes on `Fourier` see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85167/12558).

Thus reworking your case

```
n1 = (n + 1)/2;
T1 = Join[T[[n1 ;; -1]], T[[1 ;; n1 - 1]]];
InverseFourier[T1]
```

giving

```
{1.67578 + 0. I, 2.1491 - 3.70074*10^-17 I, -0.679701 + 0. I, 
 0.434838 + 0. I, -0.350779 + 1.46701*10^-16 I, 
 0.327006 + 0. I, -0.345251 + 0. I, 
 0.419201 - 1.09694*10^-16 I, -0.630195 + 0. I}
```

As you can see all the imaginary parts are zero or numerical noise. You can remove this by using `Chop`.  Note that for an even number of points you have to replace n1 with slightly different values.

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly! (even if the Impulse Response I've got was in the reverse order; easy to solve).

Comment: I'm glad it works. Happy to help. If the my answer solves your problem please accept it.